# Can MongoDB Realm be used to sync remote data to local db (rather than the opposite as advertised)?

Tags: database, mongodb, realm

I have a mobile app that needs to sync some tables from a remote db to the local db to use when it's offline, and then sync with remote db to update local records/data whenever it's online. I've stumbled upon MongoDB Realm and was wondering if it could support this behavior. Everything I've read so far on it seems to suggest the opposite: syncing local changes to remote db.

Would also appreciate any alternative suggestions.

Comment: Good answer below but the question makes it sound like you already have an existing database? Can you clarify? Also note that Realm does not have tables as it's an Object database (backed by NoSQL at the server).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Atlas Device Sync works in both directions - it will upload local data to Atlas and also stream changes from Atlas to the local device. The data is stored locally in a Realm database, so it's fully available and queryable when offline. Once the device reconnects to the internet, any changes that have occurred in the meantime will be automatically sent to the device.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll mark this as solved after trying it out :)